# Node.js with Cloudflare instead of Nginx

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nginx, cloudflare

I have created a blog with Node.js, Express and MongoDB, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Can I use CloudFlare instead of NGINX, or use both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have another web server running you would not need NGINX.  However, if you are using NGINX as your web server, you would want to use both.